# can I automatically disconnect bluetooth devices on sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, bluetooth

We use a Belkin SongStream BT to play music on a stereo via BlueTooth.
I'd like our various devices to automatically disconnect before they go to sleep.

Alternatively, the Belkin device could drop the connection once the device goes away or it could allow new devices to connect even if there was another connection previously. The device doesn't do either though and I don't think I can configure it to.

However, shouldn't it be possible to have a MacBook automatically disconnect before sleep?

As it stands now, the LED stays on at night and I have to unplug/replug the cable to be able to connect when my girlfriend takes her connected laptop to work.

It would also be sufficient to turn off Bluetooth on sleep, since I don't use a Keyboard/Mouse that needs to be able to wake the computer.